# preg_replace(): No ending matching delimiter '&gt;'

Tags: php, proxy

I have this code to create a simple proxy.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://google.co.uk';
$page = file($url);

foreach ($page as $part){
    $part = preg_replace('<img src=', '<img src='.$url,$part);
    $part = preg_replace('action="', 'action="'.$url,$part);

    echo $part;
}
?>
```

and getting these errors.

```
preg_replace(): No ending matching delimiter '&gt;'
```

and

```
preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash
```

#### Solved...

Replacing with these lines.

```
$part = preg_replace('/src="/', 'src="' . $url, $part);
$part = preg_replace('/action="/', 'action="' . $url, $part);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to place [delimiters](http://us.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) around your patterns:

```
$part = preg_replace('/src="/', 'src="'.$url,$part);
$part = preg_replace('/action="/', 'action="'.$url,$part);
```

Also, you can simplify this code a bit by making only a single call to `preg_replace`, like this:

```
$part = preg_replace('/(src|action)="/', '$0' . $url, $part);
```

or like this:

```
$part = preg_replace('/(?<=(src|action)=")/', $url, $part);
```

Comment: @user3110335 Well without seeing what's the input or the output I can't tell you what the issue is. Does the resulting URL look correct?

Comment: Changing to this 
$part = preg_replace('/src="/', 'src="' . $url, $part);
Worked for me.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

preg_replace() takes a regular expression as its first argument.  In this case, changing the pattern to `/<img src=/` should do the trick.  For more information, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php